# How to implement pagination efficiently with complex query

Tags: php, pagination

I am trying to come up with a method to efficiently create pagination for the following data/queries.

Problems:

1. I am storing sales in an associate array `$data['summary'][$SALE_ID]` and $data['details'][$SALE_ID]`. I need to maintain order. I am not sure if php associative arrays maintain order.
2. I would like an easy method such as `array_slice` to grab the set of data I need to display. I couldn't figure out how to do this. I tried

`$data['summary'] = array_slice($data['summary'], $offset, $limit, TRUE)`, but I am not sure if this is the best way

```
public function getData()
{
    $data = array();
    $data['summary'] = array();
    $data['details'] = array();
    $offset = $this->params['offset'];
            $limit = $this->params['limit'];

    //Returns 1 row for each item per sale. This means if the sale has 2 items, there will be two results per sale

    $sales_items_rows = $this->get_all_sale_items();

    foreach($sales_items_rows as $sale_item_row)
    {
        if (!isset($data['summary'][$sale_item_row['sale_id']]))
        {
            $data['summary'][$sale_item_row['sale_id']] = array(
                'sale_id' => $sale_item_row['sale_id'],
                'sale_time' => $sale_item_row['sale_time'],
                'sale_date' => $sale_item_row['sale_date'],
                'employee_name' => $sale_item_row['employee_name'],
                'customer_id' => $sale_item_row['customer_id'],
                'customer_name' => $sale_item_row['customer_name'],
                'payment_type'=> $sale_item_row['payment_type'],
                'comment'=> $sale_item_row['comment'],
                'items_purchased' => 0,
                'subtotal' => 0,
                'total' => 0,
                'tax' => 0,
                'profit' => 0,
            );
        }

        $data['summary'][$sale_item_row['sale_id']]['items_purchased']+=$sale_item_row['quantity_purchased'];
        $data['summary'][$sale_item_row['sale_id']]['subtotal']+=$sale_item_row['subtotal'];
        $data['summary'][$sale_item_row['sale_id']]['total']+=$sale_item_row['total'];
        $data['summary'][$sale_item_row['sale_id']]['tax']+=$sale_item_row['tax'];
        $data['summary'][$sale_item_row['sale_id']]['profit']+=$sale_item_row['profit'];

        $data['details'][$sale_item_row['sale_id']][] = $sale_item_row;
    }

$data['summary'] = array_slice($data['summary'], $offset, $limit, TRUE)
$data['details'] = array_slice($data['details'], $offset, $limit, TRUE)

    return $data;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: getting all items from the database, process them all, then only grab a subset is ofcourse highly inefficient for both the database as well as php itself. Consider to limit (with an offset) the returned set of results from the database!!

And if that really isn't possible for some reason, yes, you can use an array for that. As an array is defined as an ordered map, the order will be maintained whatever you do with the array. Ofcourse there are a lot of functions available that do alter the order (eg. all the sort functions), but normally you can trust the order of the array is the same like you created it.

But there's another option: why not let php create indices itself? As of now you store the relevant row with the ID as an index, but you can also store the ID as a value, and use an 'auto-incremental' index. That is pretty much how the database would return the data actually...

So instead of:

```
$data['summary'][$sale_item_row['sale_id']] = array(
    'items_purchased' => $sale_item_row['quantity_purchased'],
     ...
);
```

You would do:

```
$data['summary'][] = array(
    'sale_id'         => $sale_item_row['sale_id'],
    'items_purchased' => $sale_item_row['quantity_purchased'],
     ...
);
```

Now you have a perfectly ordered map, with incrementing indices, and the sale id as a 'property' of your row.

Comment: I tried to figure out a way to limit the query but it just isn't possible. But I saved a lot of memory by NOT outputting the entire result set and doing pagination.

Comment: I finally figured out a way to do a query for all a subset with a limit. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.